# How to plot overlaying time series in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a time series with the following data:

```
     Provice  Date Confirmed.cases virus fever Wuhan_Pneumonia temp wuhan sars
20     Anhui 02/09             779    30     0               0   10    25    0
21     Anhui 02/10             830     0     0              21   12    28    0
22     Anhui 02/11             860    43     0              21   12     0    0
23     Anhui 02/12             889     0     0               0   14     0    0
47 Chongqing 01/21               0     0     0              48   10    61   50
48 Chongqing 01/22               1    67     0              31   11    23   46
49 Chongqing 01/23               5    38     0              36   11    71   54
50 Chongqing 01/24              18    84     0              41    9    43    0
51 Chongqing 01/25              48    59   100              84    8   100   61
52 Chongqing 01/26              66    84     0              35    7    33  100
```

and would like to plot an overlapping time series plot using ggplot. However, when I do this the time series plot produced is distorted such as the one below. Can somebody please shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code I am using to produce the plot below:

```
ggplot(dta3, aes(x = Date, y = Confirmed.cases, color = Provice, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Having some sample data to test with would be incredibly helpful.  Without it, I would say this is a **grouping problem**.  I've encountered graphs being drawn this way when there is more than one data point per date per group, which seems to be the case here (causing the vertical lines connecting points on the same date).

Comment: Do you need `group = Provice` in `aes` ?

Comment: That's exactly the case here. I have several Provices that share the same date, but I want to overlay these separate time series in the same plot.

Comment: That makes sense, but within each group I would assume there is only one count of confirmed cases per day.  If the grouping were done correctly we wouldn't see the vertical lines each day -- again essentially joining two data points on the same day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had suspicions, and Ronak Shah voiced the same.

Does this fix it?

```
ggplot(dta3, aes(x = Date, y = Confirmed.cases, color = Provice, group = Provice)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: You guys are brilliant! This did the trick thank you and Ronak Shah!